# MFMailComposeViewController and MFMessageComposeViewController have wrong bounds after rotation in iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I have an app that mostly only uses portrait mode. However, when it presents `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController` it is able to rotate to landscape. This has worked fine until iOS 8 where they still rotate, but their bounds seem to follow the wrong orientation.

I have the app in portrait mode and present one of those controllers. When I rotate phone into landscape I get the following result:

`MFMailComposeViewController`:

[image]

`MFMessageComposeViewController`:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Here is the code for presenting the composers:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mailComposeViewController setSubject:subject];
[mailComposeViewController setMessageBody:body isHTML:NO];

[self presentViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
}];
```

**EDIT:**
If I inspect the views in the View Debugger I can see that although the `UIWindow` has rotated to landscape none of the underlaying views have. This includes `UITransitionView` and `UILayoutContainerView`.

Comment: I'm assuming your creating an exemption in AppDelegate? Can you show that code

Comment: Are you thinking about the `
application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` method? We are not using this. In stead we allow portrait and landscape in the plist and then use `shouldAutorotate` and `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in our view controllers.

Comment: Please add a demo project

Comment: Leo, I have tried replicating this behaviour in another app but I couldn't, so a demo project will probably not do any good. The app that is having this issue is very large and was developed by another team. So I guess I am mostly looking for suggestions on what could possibly cause this kind of behaviour.

Comment: How are you presenting the model? Could you add the presentation code?

Comment: Zigglzworth: I have added the code in the question now.

Comment: @NobleK That code does not reproduce the issue in a new project. You need to provide enough code that the issue is reproduced.

Comment: Aaron: Sadly, I am aware of this as I have stated in a comment above. This is a very large project with hundreds of classes (none written by me) and I am struggling to figure out why this problem is occurring. Obviously the presenting code was one of the first places I looked. I am mostly hoping that perhaps someone else has encountered this issue and can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Subclass the MFMailComposerViewController.. and the orientation methods... hope that helps

Comment: Haroon, I don't see how that would help me. To be clear, I do want them to be able to rotate. I just don't want them to be messed up like this.

Comment: I have updated the question again with observations from the View Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an solution but am sharing my experience.
I've also build an app which is following only Portrait orientation.
But when i try to open `MFMailComposeViewController` and `MFMessageComposeViewController` in any device orientation, it is coming in Portrait only.

I checked this only when i saw your issue.
I am presenting them the same way you are doing.
I am sharing Target settings and .plist entry i've used. Please see if any of them is helpful.

[image: Target General Settings]

[image: .plist Entry]

Comment: Rinto, your app is behaving like expected. You have only Portrait in your target settings and that will include `MFMailComposeViewController`. I on the other hand have Portrait, Landscape Right and Landscape Left, so my `MFMailComposeViewController` will be able to rotate to landscape, which it does. It's just that it's messed up.

Comment: Okay.
Between there is some orientation change that came with iOS 8.
U can check the same in this link. 

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523799/is-this-an-ios-8-bug-orientation-issue-on-rotation/27540586?)
I don't think there is something to do with this particular issue. Still throwing some light.

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with iOS8 related to rotation not working properly. Worth checking this first. Its a simple one line edit in the app delegate.

[UISplitViewController rotation iOS8 not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443852/uisplitviewcontroller-rotation-ios8-not-working-as-expected/28443948#28443948)

Comment: Rory, I suspected something like this myself, but I have checked and there doesn't seem to be any code like this in the project.

Comment: If the project was created by hand or created by a recent xcode then the line may not exist. It seems to have been created by xcode 5 or earlier I think, but it never removes it. Is there any other code in there which creates a UIWindow? If the storyboard has an initial controller set I believe that code is not required and it is the UIWindow creation in that function which was causing rotation issues: Hardware rotates but the window does not so you see portrait in landscape.

Answer (score -1):

Methods such as `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` and `didRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` are now deprecated in iOS 8 and replaced by `viewWillTransitionToSize:withTransitionCoordinator:`. Depending on how you're handling rotations in your app, you may have to make changes in your code to adapt to the new methods.

Comment: We are not using these methods at all. Also, I believe this would only affect our own view controllers and nok `MFMailComposeViewController`.